# Calculus problem from economics.

Tags: calculus, economics

Can someone please expleain me how from the following equation

$$\frac{dy}{de}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial i}\frac{di}{de}+\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{de}+\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{de}$$

We can get

$$\frac{dy}{de}=\frac{1}{1-E_y-t_y}(E_i\frac{di}{de}+t_e)$$

Thank you

Comment: It looks like a change in notation $\frac{\partial E}{\partial y} \to E_y$, etc., and algebra.

Comment: I am aware of the change in notation. However, I can't understand how the expression is changed algebraically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the starting point should be
$$\frac{dy}{de}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial i}\frac{di}{de}+\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{de}+\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{de}+\frac{dT}{de}.$$
Then, it follows that
$$\left(1-\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\right)\frac{dy}{de}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial i}\frac{di}{de}+\frac{dT}{de}$$
and
$$\frac{dy}{de}=\frac{\frac{\partial E}{\partial i}\frac{di}{de}+\frac{dT}{de}}{1-\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}}.$$
Finally, the equation follows from the definitions
$$E_i\equiv\frac{\partial E}{\partial i},\quad E_y\equiv\frac{\partial E}{\partial y},\quad t_y\equiv\frac{\partial T}{\partial y},\quad t_e\equiv\frac{\partial T}{\partial e}. $$

Comment: Thank you! I think I was just overthinking  (´・ω・`)